# Why memoryless implies $\mathbb{P}(X_1<X_2\mid\min(X_1,X_2)>t)=\mathbb{P}(X_1<X_2)$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, exponential-distribution

$X_i$ are independent exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda_i$.

In Ross's textbook,

\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(X_{i_1}<\cdots<X_{i_n}\mid\min_i X_i>t)&=\mathbb{P}(X_{i_1}-t<\cdots<X_{i_n}-t\mid\min_i X_i>t)
\\&=\mathbb{P}(X_{i_1}<\cdots<X_{i_n})
\end{align}
I can't figure out how to get the second equality by the very definition of memoryless
$$\mathbb{P}(X>s+t\mid X>t)=\mathbb{P}(X>s)$$
although it is true by intuition.

**Edit**: I have worked out this problem.
$$\mathbb{P}(X>s+t\mid X>t)=\mathbb{P}(X>s)$$
implies
$$\mathbb{P}(X>s+t)=\mathbb{P}(X>s)\mathbb{P}(X>t)$$
$d/ds$ on both sides:
$$f_X(s+t)=f_X(s)\mathbb{P}(X>t)$$

Only prove $\mathbb{P}(X_1<X_2<X_3\mid X_1>t,X_2>t,X_3>t)$ for convenient.

\begin{align}
&\mathbb{P}(X_1<X_2<X_3\mid X_1>t,X_2>t,X_3>t)\\
=&\frac{ \mathbb{P}( t<X_1<X_2<X_3)}{\mathbb{P}( X_1>t,X_2>t,X_3>t)}\\
=&\frac{ \int_{t<x_1<x_2}\mathbb{P}( t<x_1<x_2<X_3\mid X_1=x_1,X_2=x_2)f_{X_1}(x_1)f_{X_2}(x_2)dx_1dx_2}{\mathbb{P}( X_1>t,X_2>t,X_3>t)}\\
=&\frac{ \int_{t<x_1<x_2}\mathbb{P}(x_2<X_3)f_{X_1}(x_1)f_{X_2}(x_2)dx_1dx_2}{\mathbb{P}( X_1>t,X_2>t)\mathbb{P}(X_3>t)}\\
=&\frac{ \int_{t<x_1<x_2}\mathbb{P}(X_3>x_2-t)f_{X_1}(x_1)f_{X_2}(x_2)dx_1dx_2}{\mathbb{P}( X_1>t,X_2>t)}\\
=&\frac{ \int_{0<x_1<x_2}\mathbb{P}(X_3>x_2)f_{X_1}(x_1+t)f_{X_2}(x_2+t)dx_1dx_2}{\mathbb{P}( X_1>t)\mathbb{P}(X_2>t)}\\
=&\int_{0<x_1<x_2}\mathbb{P}(X_3>x_2)f_{X_1}(x_1)f_{X_2}(x_2)dx_1dx_2\\
=&\int_{0<x_1<x_2}\mathbb{P}(X_3>x_2>x_1|X_1=x_1,X_2=x_2)f_{X_1}(x_1)f_{X_2}(x_2)dx_1dx_2\\
=&\mathbb{P}(X_1<X_2<X_3)
\end{align}

Hope someone check this proof.

Comment: For the first question on top of your post: if $x<y$ then $x-t<y-t$.